# install mosek.fusion for python in anaconda (ubuntu)

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, fusion, mosek

I'm trying to use (and therefore install) an optimization package called mosek and more specifically to use it with python on a jupyter notebook.

It's a commercial package but since I'm working in academia, I have a free license.

This issue has been edited thanks to Paul insights.

My goal is to be able to use mosek in python 3.5 through jupyter.

**1° My issue:**

When I run the following line of code in jupyter notebook :

```
import mosek.fusion
```

I have the following error:

```
import mosek.fusion ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-81543b63d59f> in <module>()
----> 1 import mosek.fusion

ImportError: No module named 'mosek.fusion'
```

**2° What I did :**

I first downloaded and installed mosek. I also added my licence in my folder mosek. (I did all the steps described here : http://docs.mosek.com/7.1/toolsinstall/Linux_UNIX_installation_instructions.html and added my academical license as well).

I then tried to run the line of code:
`import mosek.fusion` which gave an error. 
I then tried to run:

```
import mosek
```

then I had no error. My conclusion is that mosek is (now, thanks to Paul), properly installed but that fusion module is missing.

I also search for any fusion file or folder in my mosek folder. I did not find any.

Is there a way to get this module fusion from mosek, and even better, is there a way to make it work?

Thank you all!

E.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fusion is not yet available for Python3. It will in the next major release, i.e. MOSEK 8.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is available for python 2?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it installed it to your `.local` because you installed with the `--user` flag. In other words:

```
python setup.py install --user
```

Trying running the install without the `--user` flag.  That should install it in your conda environment.

But I'm not sure that is your import problem. Perhaps the `fusion` module doesn't exist.  Try `ls`-ing what is in this folder `/home/edwin/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mosek/`.  Maybe try `from mosek import fusion`.

Comment: You are right, I install it again without --user and it installs it in my conda environment. 
I then tried your advice from mosek import fusion but I had exactly the same error as before.
I then try to look for a fusion file or folder in my mosek folder within conda, and there is no such file/folder... 
Any idea how I can get fusion ? 
I guess I will edit my question so that it gets more specific. 
Thank for your help, it helped me targeting my real issue.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to install Mosek (for using from Python) is to use the pip installer:

pip install git+http://github.com/MOSEK/Mosek.pip@v7.0.0#egg=mosek

You may also want to set the environement variable for the Mosek lisence explicitly, e.g.

os.environ.setdefault("MOSEKLM_LICENSE_FILE", license) where license is a server address or a file location.

However, Mosek Fusion is not yet available for Python 3

Comment: Thank you but I found a way to use Mosek and fusion with Python. I needed to use Python 2 instead of Python 3.

Comment: Installing via pip doesn't care whether you use Python 2 or Python 3. This is just a tool to make the install simpler and automated (maybe you have a testserver etc).

Answer (score 0):

Keep on the MOSEK website. Version 8(beta) soon to be released will support Python 3.5. Also full Anaconda support will soon be available.